# MySQL - Average column B values based on distinct column A values

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to find the average value from column B based on the distinct (country) of column A.

```
Argentina   49.5600
Argentina   31.5100
Austria     353.0700
Austria     67.8800
Belgium     6.2700
Belgium     0.1700
```

This is part of the table. I am trying to average the values in column B based on country, such as 49.5 + 31.5 averaged for only Argentina, etc.

I have tried several combinations so far with no luck.

```
select shipcountry, round(avg(freight), 1)
from Table.Orders
order by shipcountry;

select shipcountry,
    (select round(avg(freight), 1)
    from Table.Orders)
from Table.Orders
order by shipcountry;
```

The first query only returns one row with a single country and value. The second query returns the countries, but column B is averaged altogether. Is there a way to separate the averages by country?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3):

No subquery needed, you're just missing the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT shipcountry, ROUND(AVG(freight),1)
FROM Table.Orders
GROUP BY shipcountry;
```

[GROUP BY in the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I thought I had tried that earlier, but must have overlooked it.